# ActiveRecord: How to find parents whose ALL children match a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I have a `Parent` model that has many `Child`, and that `Child` also belongs to `OtherParent`.

How can i find all `Parent` where ALL of its `Child` belongs to any `OtherParent`?

In pure SQL I could do

```
Parent.find_by_sql(<<SQL)
  SELECT *
  FROM parents p
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM children
    WHERE parent_id = p.id
      AND other_parent_id IS NULL
  )
SQL
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430761/rails-how-to-query-for-all-the-objects-whose-every-association-have-an-attribut)), but I'd prefer to do it by taking advantage of ActiveRecord if possible.

Thanks!

---

I'm using Rails 4.2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: `OtherParent` and `Parent` models are different ?

Comment: Can you show the model associations?

Comment: This is called Exact Relational Division. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/what-is-the-name-of-this-type-of-query-and-what-is-an-efficient-example

Comment: So your query is giving childs which belongs to `OtherParent` or `Parent` and `OtherParent` ...... These 2 cases...... Am I right ?

Comment: Try `Parent.childrens.where("childs.other_parent_id IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: Yes..sorry...... Try `Parent.includes(:childrens).where("childs.other_parent_id IS NOT NULL").references(:childs)` Remember `includes(<should have association name>)` and `references(<original table name of the association>)`.......

Comment: It worked ?? Please let me know the result.

Comment: Well.. `Parent.includes(:childrens).where("childs.other_parent_id IS NOT NULL AND childs.parent_id = parent.id").references(:childs)` <~~~~~~ Try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `arel` can get you pretty far. The tricky part is how do you not write your entire query using `arel`'s own query syntax?

Here's a trick: when building your query using `where`, if you use `arel` conditions, you get some extra methods for free. For instance, you can tail the subquery you have there with `.exists.not`, which will get you a `(NOT ( EXISTS (subquery)))` Toss that into parent's `where`-clause and you're set.

The question is, how do you reference the tables involved? You need Arel for that. You **could** use Arel's `where` with its ugly conditions like `a.eq b`. But why? Since it's an equality condition, you can use Rails' conditions instead! You can reference the table you're quering with a hash key, but for the other table (in the outer query) you can use its `arel_table`. Watch this:

```ruby
parents = Parent.arel_table
Parent.where(
  Child.where(other_parent_id: nil, parent_id: parents[:id]).exists.not
)
```

You can even reduce Arel usage by resorting to strings a little and relying on the fact that you can feed in subqueries as parameters to Rails' `where`. There is not much use to it, but it doesn't force you to dig into Arel's methods too much, so you can use that trick or other SQL operators that take a subquery (are there even any others?):

```
parents = Parent.arel_table
Parent.where('NOT EXISTS (?)',
  Child.where(parent_id: parents[:id], other_parent_id: nil)
)
```

The two main points here are:

- You can build subqueries just the same way you are used to building regular queries, referencing the outer query's table with Arel. It may not even be a real table, it may be an alias! Crazy stuff.
- You can use subqueries as parameters for Rails' `where` method just fine.

Comment: I came to the exact same solution after some modifications to @ABMagil answer, but since your answer works without modifications, I'm marking it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Using Arel over pure SQL also has the advantage of returning a ActiveRecord ::Relation, instead of an array, thus allowing method chaining later!

Comment: @FelipeZavan I'm not done yet :D Fiddling with Arel is quite fun actually.

Comment: I'm starting to like it too! haha
This looks quite nice when put inside a named scope in Parent:

`where(
  Child.where(other_parent_id: nil).where(
    Child.arel_table[:parent_id].eq(arel_table[:id])
  ).exists.not
)`

Comment: @FelipeZavan as it turns out, you don't even need `eq`.

Comment: @FelipeZavan leave that to others :) Have faith in the community.

Comment: Well it seems like it's as far as you can get without sacrificing readability or extracting code fur reuse in future. I haven't found a way to get an Arel condition of an association. That would have made it even nicer.

Comment: Okay, so lesson learned: you can perfectly use `arel_table`s fields in regular Rails queries and it will work as expected. Moreover, **`arel` table aliases** work too!

Answer (score 2):

Using the exceptional [scuttle](http://scuttle.io), you can translate arbitrary SQL into ruby (ActiveRecord and ARel queries)

From that tool, your query converts to

```
Parent.select(Arel.star).where(
  Child.select(Arel.star).where(
    Child.arel_table[:parent_id].eq(Parent.arel_table[:id]).and(Child.arel_table[:other_parent_id].eq(nil))
  ).ast
)
```

Splitting up the query-

- `Parent.select(Arel.star)` will query for all columns in the Parent table.
- `Child.arel_table` brings you into Arel-world, allowing you a little bit more power in generating your query from ruby.  Specifically, `Child.arel_table[:parent_id]` gives you a handle onto an Arel::Attributes::Attribute that you can continue to use while building a query.
- the `.eq` and `.and` methods do exactly what you would expect, letting you build a query of arbitrary depth and complexity.

Not necessarily "cleaner", but entirely within ruby, which is nice.

Comment: I don't know how I've forgot such an awesome tool as Scuttle, thanks for reminding me! Unfortunately the generated code doesn't work (`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`), but with a little googling I adapted it and now it works: `Parent.select(Arel.star).where(
  Child.select(Arel.star).where(
    Child.arel_table[:parent_id].eq(Parent.arel_table[:id]).and(Child.arel_table[:other_parent_id].eq(nil))
  ).exists.not
)`

Answer (score -1):

Given `Parent` and `Child`, and child is in a `belongs_to` relationship with `OtherParent` (Rails defaults assumed):

`Parent.joins(:childs).where('other_parent_id = ?', other_parent_id)`

Comment: Can you help me to understand that, what does it mean by _Child also belongs to OtherParent_ ?

Comment: @joseramonc Thanks, but I think you missunderstood my question, please read it again and tell me if you have any questions.