# Rails ActiveRecord how do I find all records where the record is not joined with a particular other record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to search for all users (`Users`) who are not part of group 1 (`Groups`), joined by `UserGroups`, i.e. "find all users that do not have a UserGroups record binding them to Group 1."

I can find all users with `User.all` or find them by name with `User.where('name like ?' , '%'+params[:search]+'%')`

I can even find those that have **no** memberships:

```
User.includes(:user_groups).where( :user_groups => { :user_id => nil } )
```

But how do I say, "find all `Users` that are not members of group 1?"

UPDATE: here is valid SQL for it:

```
select * from Users as u where not exists (select 1 from UserGroups where group_id = 1 and user_id = u.id);
```

or, if you prefer the cached `NOT IN`

```
select * from Users as u where u.id not in (select user_id from UserGroups where group_id = 1);
```

UPDATE:

Only way I found to do it right now is raw SQL, but would love a true ActiveRecord method:

```
User.where('name like ? and id not in (select user_id from UserGroups where group_id = ?)' , '%'+params[:search]+'%',@group.id)
```

Comment: try this -- `User.includes(:user_groups).where( "user_groups.user_id != users.id AND group_id = ? ",@group.id ).where("name LIKE ?", '%'+params[:search]+'%' ).references(:user_groups)`

Comment: Hmm @R_O_R, different. Instead of not in, using a join.

Comment: @deith well, you got the desired result ?

Comment: Aye, it does, @R_O_R, but I was trying to do it ActiveRecord. look at answer by D-Side, brilliant.

Comment: Ok.. I didn't test the code I have given, that is why I was confirming by you too see if my logic bogus or not.. :p thanks for giving it a try..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
select user_id from UserGroups where group_id = 1;
```

...is essentially:

```
@group.user_groups.select(:user_id)
```

- Methods like this are present in `has_many` associations. For building subqueries, it seems.

So this:

```
select * from Users as u
where u.id not in (select user_id from UserGroups where group_id = 1);
```

Is this:

```
User.where.not(id: @group.user_groups.select(:user_id))
```

- The value in conditions is a `Relation` so it is embedded as a subquery.

And this:

```
select * from Users as u
where not exists
  (
    select 1 from UserGroups
    where group_id = 1 and user_id = u.id
  );
```

Is... The only tricky part is that we have to reference outer table's value, which is not a constant in the query. So we have to reference table's field the other way. A bit of Arel will do:

```
users = User.arel_table # `arel_table` is a sign of some serious SQL business
User.where(@group.user_groups.where(user_id: users[:id]).exists.not)
```

You may also want to look at [one of my other recent answers about `NOT EXTSTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535263/activerecord-how-to-find-parents-whose-all-children-match-a-condition/30538422#30538422).

You could also use `ids` from a "has many through", but I'm not aware if it will fetch them from the join model, not the joined one.

Comment: Dang, @D-side, that is cool. It *almost* works. The problem is that `@group.user_group_ids` is equivalent to `select id from UserGroups where group_id = 1` and *not* `select user_id from ....`. (the difference is it is selecting `id` from the join table and not `user_id`). If I could do that, I would love it.

Comment: And I am fine with `NOT IN` instead of `NOT EXISTS`, as it allows caching, as numerous people pointed out.

Comment: Hmm, not quite, it returns all users... I will check the SQL in a few mins

Comment: Hold on, that was the `NOT EXISTS` case that did that. I am trying for the `NOT IN` now...

Comment: Brilliant, you are! I don't know about the `NOT EXISTS`, but the `NOT IN` works amazingly! Hats off!

Comment: @deitch I didn't still looked into the `Arel` one. I should in near future if needed. Till now, I am good with old active record.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause try to use 'field not in list' like so.

```
User.includes(:user_groups).where('user_id not in (?)', :group_1_id)
```

Replace `group_1_id` with the identifier for Group 1 in your case.
I got it from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4307411/1566187).

I did not test it though. So you might try around with the concrete syntax.

Comment: But would that not filter out *all* users who have any membership? I want to filer out just those who don't have membership in group 1. If a User has a membership in group 2, I want to list them.

Comment: Not sure what :user_groups is in your case. Maybe replace it with the specific id of the group you want to exclude.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are using `not in`, but then this is incomplete? I will try it